# Average time for mobile handset to make to setup a network connection

Tags: android, tcp

I wanted to check what the average time to setup a

1. TCP
2. HTTP
3. UDP
4. SIP

connection on mobile handset (say Android OS device) is. What I want to check is the total average time to connect between a mobile handset and server say sending just 1 byte of data.

Answer (score 0):

Write a test app that tries connection to each, records the times to setup, connect, send a byte and disconnect. Your app then repeats this several times, probably with a wait, then gives you an average.

This is also going to depend on the network type (GSM/UMTS/Wi-Fi), load on the cell, internet traffic between your handset and the destination etc.

What are you attempting to do?

Comment: The typical network would be say LTE or Wifi, I am trying to figure out the time of SIP Options Ping from West Coast to East Coast from one handset to another.  I want to know the average total time of roundtrip from one mobile handset (CA) to another (Boston say).

Comment: I am trying to use it to discover the peer to peer handset capabilities real-timish